# How to launch a coroutine in IO that can pause when lifecyle is not atleast in STARTED state

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines

Using `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted` I can start a coroutine that will pause if my activity is not in atleast started state, and will resume if when the activity goes back in started state.

I want to replicate this behavior on a coroutine that is running on IO. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    withContext(IO)
    {
        var i = 0
        while (true)
        {
            Log.i("launchWhenStarted", "STATE: ${lifecycle.currentState.name}  ${i++}")
            delay(500)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `launchWhenStarted` work without being on `IO` dispatcher? Does it start and resume properly?

Comment: @ChristianB It works on Dispatcher.Main.Immediate & yes it resumes properly.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code, it works fine for me. I also do not see why it should not work with any other Dispatcher. So there must be something else we do not see.

Comment: @ChristianB Did you use the same code? And did the Log.i line stopped logging when the activity went to stopped state?

Comment: Yes I used the same code. When I leave the Activity, `onStop()` was called and the Coroutine stopped as well (no logs). And no matter which `Dispatcher` I used.